# Weakly compact subset of a normed space is sequentially compact, norm bounded, and proximal

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

Studying for topological vector spaces I came across this problem:

> Let $E$ be a normed space and let $K$ be a weakly compact subset of $E$.
>   Then $K$ is sequentially compact, norm bounded and proximal.

We know that the dual space is a Banach space so from the weak compactness we can conclude that for every $ f \in E^*$ $$ \sup\{|f(x)|,x\in K\} < \infty$$ and from the uniform boundedness principle we get that $K$ is norm bounded.
Now assuming that there exists a sequence $x_n$ with no convergent subsequence we fix $x\in K$ , $r>0$ and we consider the sets $$\{n\in \mathbb N:\|x_n-x\|>r\}$$ which have to be infinite. Doesn't this contradict the fact that $x_n$ is bounded?
What about $K$ being proximal?

Comment: You can't show $K$ is sequentially compact in norm, which is what it appears you're trying to do (consider the unit ball in any $\ell^p$ space).  You can, however, show that $K$ is *weakly* sequentially compact.